# Installing xdebug on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 using pecl

Tags: osx-lion, pecl, xdebug

Im trying to get the xdebug environment up and running om my mac os x lion box using pecl.

I got the latest version of xcode installed and linked the binaries

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/autoconf /usr/bin/autoconf
sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/autoheader /usr/bin/autoheader
sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/autom4te /usr/bin/autom4te
```

But when trying to install the xdebug itself...

```
$ sudo pecl install xdebug
Password:
downloading xdebug-2.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.1.2.tgz (304,229 bytes)
..............................................................done: 304,229 bytes
66 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Can't locate Autom4te/C4che.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/bin/../share/autoconf /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/bin/autom4te line 43.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/autom4te line 43.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Since I'm not a *nix developer (yet) this becomes a bit troublesome. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the 3 symlinks you already mentioned in your question, you'll also need this one:

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/share/autoconf /usr/share/autoconf
```

Then `phpize` should run without error.